# using a strtok() token with fscanf() to do a date assignment

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, singly-linked-list

I have this struct named TEAM which holds several information regarding a football team.

```
    typedef struct team{
    int     ID;                 //1
    char    Team_name[MAX_LEN]; //2
    int     Status;             //3
    int     Points;             //4
    int     Score;              //5
    int     Goals;              //6
    struct tm  Date;            //7
    struct team *next;
}TEAM;
```

I am creating a linked list of teams and team information is read from a file and it is in the following format:

```
ID;teamname;status;points;score;goals;day/month/year hour:minute
```

I have no problem getting the data from the file and doing the required assignments. However I am having problem with the date part.

I use strtok() to split a line into tokens and I try to use the following code to assign the parts of the token to their respective variables.

```
fscanf(token, "%d/%d/%d %d:%d", &tmp->Date.tm_mday, &tmp->Date.tm_mon, &tmp->Date.tm_year, &tmp->Date.tm_hour, &tmp->Date.tm_min);
```

But this gives this return value
-1073741819 (0xC0000005)
which is as far as I know known as illegal memory access something I did with '&' symbol or fscanf() is wrong.

My code works fine without fscanf() so what am I doing wrong?

Edit: The whole code:

```
typedef struct team{
    int     ID;                 //1
    char    Team_name[MAX_LEN]; //2
    int     Status;             //3
    int     Points;             //4
    int     Score;              //5
    int     Goals;              //6
    struct tm  Date;            //7
    struct team *next;
}TEAM;

TEAM *createNode(void){
    TEAM *node;
    node = (TEAM *)malloc(sizeof(TEAM));
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

TEAM *initialiseTeams(void){
    FILE    *fp;
    TEAM    *head;
    TEAM    *tmp;
    char    line[BUFFER];
    char    *token;
    const char delim[2] = ";";

    fp = fopen("Teams.txt","r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Failed to open Teams.txt\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    head = createNode();
    tmp  = head;
    while(fgets(line, BUFFER, fp)){

        int i;

        for(i = 0, token = strtok(line, delim); token != NULL; i++, token = strtok(NULL, delim)){
            printf("%s\n", token);
            switch(i){
                case 0: // ID
                    tmp->ID = atoi(token);
                    break;
                case 1: // Team name
                    strcpy(tmp->Team_name, token);
                    break;
                case 2: // Status
                    if(strcmp(token, "L") == 0){
                        tmp->Status = 0;
                    }

                    if(strcmp(token, "W") == 0){
                        tmp->Status = 1;
                    }

                    if(strcmp(token, "D") == 0){
                        tmp->Status = 2;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3: // Points
                    tmp->Points = atoi(token);
                    break;
                case 4: // Score
                    tmp->Score = atoi(token);
                    break;
                case 5: // Goals
                    tmp->Goals = atoi(token);
                    break;
                case 6: // Date
                    fscanf(token, "%d/%d/%d %d:%d", &tmp->Date.tm_mday, &tmp->Date.tm_mon, &tmp->Date.tm_year, &tmp->Date.tm_hour, &tmp->Date.tm_min);
                    break;
            }
        }
        tmp->next   = createNode();
        tmp         = tmp->next;
    }

    free(tmp);
    return head;
}

int main(void){
    TEAM    *head;
    head = initialiseTeams();
}
```

Comment: We can't debug incomplete code fragments. Please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Now run your program in a debugger and find out which exact line of code it is crashing on. When you get that then dump the variables to see whether any of the pointer values are invalid. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The code you have shown does not have the line of code you described: `//fscanf(token, "%d/%d/%d %d:%d", tmp->Date.tm_mday, tmp->Date.tm_mon, tmp->Date.tm_year, tmp->Date.tm_hour, tmp->Date.tm_min);`. That is both commented out and doesn't have the required `&`'s in it. Please give the actual non-working code. It's not clear whether your real code has the missing `&`'s or not.

Comment: thank you for that link! I did enabled all warnings which said "|warning: passing argument 1 of 'fscanf' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|" so changing fscanf to sscanf did the trick.

Comment: edited the code in the way that produced my problem @kaylum
I guess I should beware of the warnings. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wildly over-complicating creating your list. This is partially due to trying to offload all I/O and list operations to the `initialiseTeams()`. Generally you want to keep your list operations separate from your program interface (the I/O, how it interacts with the user, etc..) That way, regardless of where you need to add a node from (file, user-input, etc..), you can simply call an `add()` (or `push()`) function to add a new node to your list.

You have done a good job separating the `createnode()` function. You can utilize it further by passing a pointer to a `TEAM` struct as a parameter that can be used to initialize the new node in the `createnode()` function. For example:

```c
TEAM *createNode (TEAM *t)
{
    TEAM *node = malloc (sizeof *node);   /* allocate */
    
    if (!node) {                          /* validate */
        perror ("malloc-node");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    if (t)                                /* assign struct (if not NULL) */
      *node = *t;
    node->next = NULL;
    
    return node;
}
```

It take very little extra effort. There is no reason to call your `createnode()` function until you have validated the data to add, so passing a `TEAM*` pointer allows you to handle all the creation and initialization in the function.

Your `initialiseTeams()` should take an open `FILE*` stream to read from as a parameter. If the file cannot be opened and validate back in the caller -- there is no need to call the `initialiseTeams()` function to begin with.

You can read with `fgets()` as you do, but there is no need to tokenize the line with `strtok()`. A simple carefully crafted `sscanf()` format string will do. This greatly simplifies your function, reducing the implementation to:

```c
/* read all records from fp, return pointer to beginning of list */
TEAM *initialiseTeams (FILE *fp)
{
    char line[BUFFER];
    TEAM *head = NULL,      /* using both head & tail pointer allows O(1) in-order */
         *tail = NULL;      /* insertions to the list. */
    
    while (fgets (line, BUFFER, fp)) {          /* read each line */
        TEAM tmp = { .ID = 0 };                 /* temporary struct */
        /* parse values with sscanf() validating return */
        if (sscanf (line, "%d; %127[^;]; %d; %d; %d; %d; %d/%d/%d %d:%d",
                    &tmp.ID, tmp.Team_name, &tmp.Status, &tmp.Points,
                    &tmp.Score, &tmp.Goals, &tmp.Date.tm_mday, &tmp.Date.tm_mon, 
                    &tmp.Date.tm_year, &tmp.Date.tm_hour, &tmp.Date.tm_min) == 11) {
            
            TEAM *node;                         /* node to allocate */
            if (!(node = createNode (&tmp)))    /* create node passing tmp struct */
                break;
            
            tmp.Date.tm_year -= 1900;           /* subtract 1900 from year */
            *node = tmp;                        /* assign tmp to allocated node */
            
            if (!head)                          /* if head NULL, add 1st node */
                head = tail = node;
            else {
                tail->next = node;              /* add all subsequent nodes in-order */
                tail = node;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return head;    /* return pointer to beginning of list */
}
```

(**note:** you will need to adjust the *field-width* modifier in `"%127[^;]"` to whatever you have for `MAX_LEN - 1`)

Never hard-code filenames or use *MagicNumbers* in your code. You should not have to re-compile your program just to read from a different filename. Either provide the name of the filename as an argument to your program (that's what `int argc, char **argv` are for in `int main (int argc, char **argv)` or prompt the user to input the filename. Since you show `MAX_LEN` and `BUFFER`, those are obviously declared as constants elsewhere -- which is good.

Taking the filename to read from as the first argument to your program, or reading from `stdin` by default if no argument is provided, your program to read you data file could be similar to:

```c
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    TEAM    *head = NULL;   /* initialize pointers NULL */
    /*
     * keep interface separate from implementation.
     * open file/validate and pass open FILE* to initialiseTeams()
     * use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default)
     */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    head = initialiseTeams (fp);    /* read all records in file into list */
    
    if (fp != stdin)    /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
    
    prn_list (head);    /* print list */
    del_list (head);    /* free all nodes */
}
```

Putting it altogether, and writing quick `prn_list()` and `del_list()` functions to output the list and then to delete all nodes in the list when you are done, you could do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_LEN 128
#define BUFFER 1024

typedef struct team {
    int  ID;
    char Team_name[MAX_LEN];
    int  Status;
    int  Points;
    int  Score;
    int  Goals;
    struct tm Date;
    struct team *next;
} TEAM;

TEAM *createNode (TEAM *t)
{
    TEAM *node = malloc (sizeof *node);   /* allocate */
    
    if (!node) {                          /* validate */
        perror ("malloc-node");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    if (t)                                /* assign struct (if not NULL) */
      *node = *t;
    node->next = NULL;
    
    return node;
}

/* read all records from fp, return pointer to beginning of list */
TEAM *initialiseTeams (FILE *fp)
{
    char line[BUFFER];
    TEAM *head = NULL,      /* using both head & tail pointer allows O(1) in-order */
         *tail = NULL;      /* insertions to the list. */
    
    while (fgets (line, BUFFER, fp)) {          /* read each line */
        TEAM tmp = { .ID = 0 };                 /* temporary struct */
        /* parse values with sscanf() validating return */
        if (sscanf (line, "%d; %127[^;]; %d; %d; %d; %d; %d/%d/%d %d:%d",
                    &tmp.ID, tmp.Team_name, &tmp.Status, &tmp.Points,
                    &tmp.Score, &tmp.Goals, &tmp.Date.tm_mday, &tmp.Date.tm_mon, 
                    &tmp.Date.tm_year, &tmp.Date.tm_hour, &tmp.Date.tm_min) == 11) {
            
            TEAM *node;                         /* node to allocate */
            if (!(node = createNode (&tmp)))    /* create node passing tmp struct */
                break;
            
            tmp.Date.tm_year -= 1900;           /* subtract 1900 from year */
            *node = tmp;                        /* assign tmp to allocated node */
            
            if (!head)                          /* if head NULL, add 1st node */
                head = tail = node;
            else {
                tail->next = node;              /* add all subsequent nodes in-order */
                tail = node;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return head;    /* return pointer to beginning of list */
}

/* simple print function */
void prn_list (TEAM *list)
{
    if (!list) {
        puts ("(list empty)");
        return;
    }
    
    for (TEAM *iter = list; iter; iter = iter->next)
        printf ("%4d  %s\n"
                "  Status: %d\n"
                "  Points: %d\n"
                "  Score : %d\n"
                "  Goals : %d\n"
                "  Date  : %d/%d/%d %d:%d\n\n",
                iter->ID, iter->Team_name, iter->Status, iter->Points, iter->Score,
                iter->Goals, iter->Date.tm_mday, iter->Date.tm_mon, 
                iter->Date.tm_year + 1900, iter->Date.tm_hour, iter->Date.tm_min);
}

/* function to delete all nodes in list */
void del_list (TEAM *list)
{
    while (list) {
        TEAM *victim = list;
        list = list->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    TEAM    *head = NULL;   /* initialize pointers NULL */
    /*
     * keep interface separate from implementation.
     * open file/validate and pass open FILE* to initialiseTeams()
     * use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default)
     */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    head = initialiseTeams (fp);    /* read all records in file into list */
    
    if (fp != stdin)    /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
    
    prn_list (head);    /* print list */
    del_list (head);    /* free all nodes */
}
```

Testing the code with a generated data file that meets your format of:

```
ID;teamname;status;points;score;goals;day/month/year hour:minute
```

**Example Input File**

For example:

```
$ cat dat/soccerteams.txt
42;Team42;3;0;0;2;9/2/2020 1:5
97;Team97;6;42;2;2;18/3/2020 2:11
54;Team54;2;35;0;4;9/4/2020 3:17
49;Team49;10;0;2;4;18/5/2020 4:23
46;Team46;7;28;8;1;18/6/2020 5:29
98;Team98;7;0;4;3;27/1/2020 6:35
15;Team15;2;7;6;0;9/2/2020 7:41
8;Team8;8;7;4;3;27/3/2020 8:47
4;Team4;4;28;8;4;18/4/2020 9:53
51;Team51;12;14;6;1;9/5/2020 10:59
```

**Example Use/Output**

Calling the program as follows results in the output shown:

```
$ ./bin/ll_soccer dat/soccerteams.txt
  42  Team42
  Status: 3
  Points: 0
  Score : 0
  Goals : 2
  Date  : 9/2/2020 1:5

  97  Team97
  Status: 6
  Points: 42
  Score : 2
  Goals : 2
  Date  : 18/3/2020 2:11

  54  Team54
  Status: 2
  Points: 35
  Score : 0
  Goals : 4
  Date  : 9/4/2020 3:17

  49  Team49
  Status: 10
  Points: 0
  Score : 2
  Goals : 4
  Date  : 18/5/2020 4:23

  46  Team46
  Status: 7
  Points: 28
  Score : 8
  Goals : 1
  Date  : 18/6/2020 5:29

  98  Team98
  Status: 7
  Points: 0
  Score : 4
  Goals : 3
  Date  : 27/1/2020 6:35

  15  Team15
  Status: 2
  Points: 7
  Score : 6
  Goals : 0
  Date  : 9/2/2020 7:41

   8  Team8
  Status: 8
  Points: 7
  Score : 4
  Goals : 3
  Date  : 27/3/2020 8:47

   4  Team4
  Status: 4
  Points: 28
  Score : 8
  Goals : 4
  Date  : 18/4/2020 9:53

  51  Team51
  Status: 12
  Points: 14
  Score : 6
  Goals : 1
  Date  : 9/5/2020 10:59
```

When you separate your list operation from the rest of your program, it makes testing each individual component much easier and makes your list code reusable. If you put everything together in a few large functions -- then you will end up having to rewrite them for every list in the future. Keep functions small and easy to test.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

`fscanf` takes a `FILE *` as its first argument, but you describe your code as passing `token` which came from strtok somehow.  You don't say what `token` is, but there's no way to get a `FILE *` from strtok, so it is probably not that.

Perhaps you mean to call `sscanf`?